# Jest: Couldn't find preset "@babel/env" relative to directory

Tags: node.js, jestjs, babeljs

I'm trying to set up Jest in an ES6 project. Didn't get far, since as soon as I run `jest`, I start running into problems.

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/env"
  ]
}
```

The above throws a `Couldn't find preset "@babel/env" relative to directory` error when running Jest. Which is fine I guess, since it should be `@babel/preset-env` either way? (both work with the rest of my setup though...)

But! When I change the preset to `@babel/preset-env`, the error I'm receiving is very confusing:

> Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.3". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel. (While processing preset: "/Users/.../node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")

Which is very strange, since my devDeps of Babel and Jest are set to:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.2.0",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
  "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
  "babel-jest": "^23.6.0"
}
```

As far as I can tell, that error message makes exactly zero sense. My next thought was to check my global Babel CLI installation, which was `babel-cli@6.26.0`. Closer, but it's not `6.26.3` as stated in the error message. I also tried replacing the global package with the latest `@babel/cli`, but it made no difference.

What might I be missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, solved it. For some very strange reason, I had to include `'babel-core@^7.0.0-0'` in my local setup, which I found out at the [babel-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-jest) npmjs page (screenshot below):

[image: 2]]

So basically, running `npm i -D 'babel-core@^7.0.0-0'` solved my problem, leaving my devDeps like this:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
  "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
  "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
  "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
}
```

Including both `@babel/core` and `babel-core` seems like madness to me, but hey, it works! The `6.26.3` error message remains a mystery I guess, since I can't find any Babel package at all at that version, neither local or global...